# Error installing pip

Tags: 16.04, python, pip

I'm trying to reinstall PIP as I'm having problems using it behind a proxy (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495375/python-pip-install-throws-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-retry)). By trying to use the `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531821/616413) I got the following errors:

`sudo apt-get remove python-pip python3-pip` (ok)
`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` (ok)
`sudo python get-pip.py`

generates the error:

```
The directory '/home/tbrugz/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/tbrugz/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/pip/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

If I remove the `sudo` or add `--proxy` parameter the error is the same. Alternative instalation methods are welcome ;)

**Update:** forgot to say that I'm using a local CNTLM proxy to connect to an external proxy. Looks like some people had a similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975187/cant-use-cntlm-to-connect-to-pip

Comment: try this flow using virtualenv

Comment: Check the persmission of `/home/tbrugz/.cache/pip/http` and `/home/tbrugz/.cache/pip` if its not you say its `root` then change it.

Comment: @sparkmood thanks, but similar error occurs:
`Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
...
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 812, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/tbrugz/pyenv1/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1`